# Expectation of cube of summation of independent random variables

Tags: self-study, expected-value, sum

[image: test]

Where would I begin on this problem?

I know I begin with pulling $c^3$.

Where would I go from there?

And I know that $\mathbb{E}[X] = x_1p_1 + .... x_n p_n$

I'm stuck on the rest, however.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its wiki.

Comment: What you have there is not the expectation of a sum, but the expectation of the cube.

Comment: Hint: multiply out that cubic expression and note that there are three types of terms: $X_i^3, X_i^2X_j$ and $X_iX_jX_k$. Then apply the linearity of expectation and independence, keeping in mind that $X_i$ is _not_ independent of $X_j$ if $i=j$, but _is_ independent of $X_j$ when $i \neq j$.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that  $(\sum_{i =1}^n X_i)^3 = \sum_{i =1}^n X_i^3 + 3 \sum_{i \neq j} X_i X_j^2 + \sum_{i\neq j \neq k} X_i X_j X_k$

And also remember that  $ E[\sum X_i] = \sum E[X_i]  $

Lastly, since $ X_1 ,X_2, ... $ are independent, then $ E[X_1 X_2] = E[X_1]E[X_2]$

I think those are the pieces you are missing.

The rest of the process is just applying those formulas